# Remove timezone from dataframe column with datetime format

Tags: pandas, datetime, timezone

I am looking for a simple way to remove the timezone information from a dataframe column that is in the datetime format. I have tried several posted solutions, but all have led to errors:

`df['dateTime']`

```
629         2019-11-30 22:55:03-05:00
806         2019-12-01 13:30:35-05:00
1137        2019-06-05 16:09:44-04:00
1192        2019-12-01 01:29:14-05:00
1250        2019-12-01 11:42:42-05:00
                      ...            
57881807    2020-05-10 18:55:07-04:00
57882209    2020-10-28 18:31:49-04:00
57882661    2020-07-16 15:40:18-04:00
57883287    2020-04-03 12:58:29-04:00
57883574    2020-04-03 09:06:03-04:00
Name: dateTime, Length: 174796, dtype: object
```

I would like to set this column as a datetimeindex, but cannot with the timezone set to -4 or -5. I would like to strip the timezone while preserving the local time. I have tried:

`roomData[i]['dateTime'].dt.tz_localize(None)`

which yields the error:
`Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

or
`df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None))`

which yields the error:
`replace() takes no keyword arguments`

Any ideas? I have 60M data points, so converting to string, stripping the last 6 characters and re-converting to datetime is not a practical option.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert from string to datetime first.

Comment: `df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'], utc=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution:

`df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: You don't need a lambda, you have the dt accessor for datetime dtype Series: `df['dateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`. Also keep in mind that this leaves you with a column of dtype string (not datetime).